# Were you ever able to create a BOT using Office communicator 2007 R2

Tags: ms-office, bots, office-communicator

I read your post regarding creating a ChatBot using Office Communicator 2007 - I would like to know whether you ever got this answered, since I would like to create a Bot too - thanks.  I have found the references for doing OC automation - but this is not what I like to do as it uses  my current profile and cannot hold it's own conversations.  So, I have another profile that I'd like to use to hold seperate conversations with other members from the company (on my machine)

Comment: Who are you talking too? This is a what's called a multi-user site. There isn't one person posting all the questions here ;) Word your question better and you will get some responses. We haven't all read the post you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

UCMA (Unified Communications Managed API) is the recommended API for building bots - you'll want version 1.0 if you're developing against OCS 2007, version 2.0 for OCS 2007 R2, and version 3.0 for Lync Server 2010

A google for UCMA Bot Sample or something similar should get you started

Comment: Thank you , I did eventually get it going - the sample that most were using had a connector - and for some readon - they were using the RealTimeServerConnectionManager and when I changed to the RealTimeClientConnectionManager (just by fiddling) the solution began to resopnd.  So - yes thanks.